# Python split and print based on second column values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string output returned to me in the following format

```
Skip this first line of queues ...

reply_105d621c2a624832a6d10ee9767bfb0a  0

reply_36b762860c9a43b89ed33da39594db98  0

reply_5b0ada5aee034f3682ff8c6dc2600996  10

reply_36b762860c9a43b89ed33da39594db98  0

reply_5b0ada5aee034f3682ff8c6dc2600996  20

reply_36b762860c9a43b89ed33da39594db98  0

reply_5b0ada5aee034f3682ff8c6dc2600996  0
```

How can I split this string so that I skip the first line and then print only lines with values other than 0

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
queue = lines.split('\n')[1:-1]
queue = dict([i.split('\t',1) for i in queue])
queue = {k:v for (k,v) in queue.iteritems() if v!='0'}
```